# Why do string literals (char*) in C++ have to be constants?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, string-literals

I've recently been learning C++ and have realised that string literals in C++ have to be constants, whereas in C, they do not. Here is an example. The following code would be valid in C, but not in C++:

```
char* str = "Hello, World!";
```

In order to do the same thing in C++, the following statement has to be used:

```
const char* str = "Hello, World!";
```

Why is there a difference?

Comment: *" whereas in C, they do not"* Your are incorrect. String literals in C are constant, but they are allowed to be pointed to by a `char*`. You still can't modify the string through that pointer. In C++, they just eliminated that exception to const correctness to avoid confusion and mistakes.

Comment: Because that is how they designed the language.  C didn't initially have the `const` keyword, so it would break legacy code if they changed literals to require `const`-qualification after introduction of the keyword.  C's string-literals are immutable, though, so changing the contents is undefined behavior even if it's not `const`-qualified.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons then why does the following code work? ``char* str = "Hello World";
str = "Goodbye World";```

Comment: @Serket: That's not modifying the string itself; it's changing the pointer `str` (which is not a constant) to point to a different string.  `char *str = "Hello World"; str[0] = 'J';` would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! Could someone post an official answer for me to mark as correct?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you should probably copy that into an answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux C string literals are not necessarily constant. Attempting to modify a string literal (more precisely, the anonymous array object that a string literal refers to) has undefined behavior. A conforming C implementation could make that array modifiable.

Comment: @KeithThompson You can say that for pretty much any example of undefined behavior. It's constant as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: @BessieTheCow: For something to be constant as far as the standard is concerned, attempting to modify it would be a constraint or syntax violation. For example, `const int *ptr = ...; *ptr = 42;` must be diagnosed. `char *s = "hello"; *s = 'H';` does not require a diagnostic. The string literal is of type `char[6]`, not `const char[6]` (as it is in C++). (Note also that "constant" and "`const`" are not the same thing. "Constant" means the value is determined at compile time. `const` means read-only. C++ string literals are `const`.

Comment: @KeithThompson What about `const int x = 5; *(int*)&x = 42;` or `constexpr int x = 5; *(int*)&x = 42;`? That's UB no diagnostic required as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Sure, you can always cast away `const` and avoid a 
required diagnostic. The point is that string literals aren't `const`
in the first place.There are three separate rules at play: 
(a) Modifying an object via a `const` qualified lvalue is a constraint violation.
(b) Modifying an object defined with `const` has UB
(c) Modifying a string literal has UB.

Comment: @BessieTheCow The only reason modification of string literals is treated separately is to avoid breaking existing code. Making string literals `const` would have made `char *s = "hello";` a constraint violation. As it is, it's perfectly valid (but unwise) and invokes UB only if you try to modify the object `s` points to.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Expanding on [Christian Gibbons' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601872/why-do-string-literals-char-in-c-have-to-be-constants/61601994#61601994) a bit...

In C, string literals, like `"Hello, World!"`, are stored in arrays of `char` such that they are visible over the lifetime of the program.  String literals are *supposed* to be immutable, and some implementations will store them in a read-only memory segment (such that attempting to modify the literal's contents will trigger a runtime error).  Some implementations don't, and attempting to modify the literal's contents may not trigger a runtime error (it may even appear to work as intended).  The C language definition leaves the behavior "undefined" so that the compiler is free to handle the situation however it sees fit.

In C++, string literals are stored in arrays of `const char`, so that any attempt to modify the literal's contents will trigger a diagnostic *at compile time*.

As Christian points out, the `const` keyword was not originally a part of C.  It was, however, originally part of C++, and it makes using string literals a little safer.

Remember that the `const` keyword *does not* mean "store this in read-only memory", it only means "this thing may not be the target of an assignment."

Also remember that, unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `*` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In C++, when you write

```
const char *str = "Hello, world";
```

the *address* of the first character of the string is stored to `str`.  You can set `str` to point to a *different* string literal:

```
str = "Goodbye cruel world";
```

but what you *cannot* do is modify the contents of the string, something like

```
str[0] = 'h';
```

or

```
strcpy( str, "Something else" );
```

Comment: IMO a correct answer. I'd probably stress out more that in `const char *s="foo";` the `const` is telling something only about the pointer (cannot be used for writing), but tells nothing about the pointed-to object. Unfortunately a lot of C++ programmers (and even the standard library) confuses the two especially with references (i.e. in `const X& x` the keyword `const` is relative to the **reference** only and tells nothing about the referenced object; passing a `const&` is **not** a smart way to pass by value as you can run into lifetime or aliasing problems).

Comment: @6502: `const char *str` means that the pointed-to object is `const`, not the pointer.  We can write a new value to `str` (point it to a different object), but not to `*str` or `str[i]`.  `char * const str` means that the pointer itself is `const` and cannot be written to, but the thing it points to can be.

Comment: No. The declaration `const char *str;` is a declaration of a "read only pointer" , i.e. a pointer that can be used for reading only... but that is a property of the pointer, it tells nothing about const-ness of pointed object. The pointed object can change, simply it cannot be changed **using that pointer** (but there can be for example other read/write pointers to the same object). A `const char *` is not a pointer to char that is const, it's a pointer to a char that cannot be used for writing.

Comment: @6502: =*sigh*= You're right - I hadn't had my coffee yet.

Comment: @6502 I'm confused now. In [this post about the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), David Anderson states that `const char *chptr;` means *chptr is a pointer to a char constant*. Is he wrong? Or is it just a simplification and one has to add that the pointed-to object is only constant from the viewpoint of the current pointer?

Comment: @Splines: code like `char x = 'A'; const char *p = &x; printf("%c\n", *p); x = 'B'; printf("%c\n", *p);` is perfectly valid and the output must be `A\nB\n` (see https://godbolt.org/z/rjx64TjMG). So `p` is not a pointer to a constant because what is pointed to changes! Sure you cannot change it using `p` (without a cast) but this doesn't make the pointed object a constant in the absolute sense. `p` is a pointer that cannot be used to write (that's why I would prefer "readonly pointer"). Note however that **string literals** ARE constants, thus trying to modify them is UB.

Comment: @6502 Thanks for this clarification and the example. Got it now.

Answer (score 28):

C didn't initially have the `const` keyword, so it would break legacy code if they changed literals to require `const`-qualification after introduction of the keyword. C's string-literals are immutable, though, so changing the contents is undefined behavior even if it's not `const`-qualified.

C++, on the other hand, was designed with the `const` keyword.  Initially, C++ did allow for string literals to be assigned to non `const`-qualified `char *`s presumably for compatibility with existing C code.  As of the [C++03](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B03) standard, however, they decided to deprecate this functionality rather than allowing the dissonance to continue into perpetuity.  I would guess the amount of legacy C++ code relying on non-`const` qualified `char *`s pointing to string literals to be small enough that it was a worthy trade-off.

Comment: Note that C++ initially allowed non-const `char*` to literals. But it was deprecated and officially removed in C++11. So even if C++ was originally designed with `const` in mind, that exception to the rule was left it for a while.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't until C++03 that the behavior was deprecated.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I'll try to find the best wording to fix the C++ angle of the answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Okay, I've made some modifications to the C++ section of the answer.  I tried not to let it fall too hard into opinion.