# Error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to struct

Tags: c++, initializer

VA2022 (17.0.6), Windows 10 x64.

When I build the C++ pgm below (debug build), I get an error message

```
C20vsC17.cpp(18,4): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'main::V'
C20vsC17.cpp(19,2): message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

What is the reason for this error?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct V
    {
        char name[25];
        void *pValue;

        V(char *nameIn, void *pValueIn)
        {
            strcpy_s(name, nameIn); pValue = pValueIn;
        }
    };

    V var[] =
    {
            { "Name", nullptr }
    };
}
```

Comment: `V(char *nameIn, void *pValueIn)` should be `V(const char *nameIn, void *pValueIn)`

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `std::string`, as it will make your life easier.

Comment: Related to the problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601872/why-do-string-literals-char-in-c-have-to-be-constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601872/why-do-string-literals-char-in-c-have-to-be-constants)

Comment: @drescherjm - fixed the error, tnx.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: I wish. `std::string` doesn't play well with the Windows APIs.

Comment: However, `std::string::c_str()` plays nicely with Windows APIs.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. For instance, `GetWindowText()`. And a lot more. Good for constant strings, though.

Comment: @Woody20 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve