# understand how char works in c++

Tags: c++

I am a C++ newbie. Although many similar questions have been asked and answered, I still find these concepts confusing.
I know

```
char c='a'            // declare a single char c and assign value 'a' to it
char * str = "Test";  // declare a char pointer and pointing content str, 
                      // thus the content can't be modified via point str
char str1[] = "Test"; // declare a char array str1 and assign "Test" to it
                      // thus str1 owns the data and can modify it
```

my first question is `char * str`  creates a pointer, how does `char * str = "Test";` work? assign a string literal to a pointer? It doesn't make sense to me although it is perfectly legal, I think we can only assign an address to a pointer, however `"Test"` is a string literal not an address.

Second question is how come the following code prints out "Test" twice in a row?

```
char str2[] = {'T','e','s','t'};  // is this line legal? 
                                 // intializing a char array with initilizer list, seems to be okay to me
cout<<str2<<endl;               // prints out "TestTest"
```

why `cout<<str2<<endl;` prints out "TestTest"?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between `char s[]` and `char* s`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1704407/11082165), [Why do string literals (char*) in C++ have to be constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61601872/11082165), [What is the datatype of string literal in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12517983/11082165)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux For ````char * str = "Test";````, in Clion, it did not even throw an warning, in ubuntu terminal, compiler gives an warning saying  ````warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]````, but it still runs fine. My g++ is  9.3.0

Comment: Re: "why `cout<<str2<<endl;` prints out "TestTest"?", that's a duplicate of [Printing char arrays c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507641/11082165)

Comment: Sometimes it's good practice to check your code with an online compiler, such as [ideone](https://ideone.com/l/cpp), and see if you get the same result. You can even share it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char * str = "Test";`  is not allowed in C++. A string literal can only be pointed to by a pointer to `const`. You would need `const char * str = "Test";`.

If your compiler accepts `char * str = "Test";` it is likely outdated. This conversion has not been allowed since C++11 (which came out over 10 years ago).

---

> how does char * str = "Test"; work?

String literals are implicitly convertible to a pointer to the start of the literal. In C++ arrays are implicitly convertible to pointer to their first element. For example `int x[10]` is implicitly convertible to `int*`, the conversion results in `&(x[0])`. This applies to string literals, their type is a const array of characters (`const char[]`).

---

> how come the following code prints out "Test" twice in a row?

In C++ most features related to character strings assume the string is null terminated, which is implied in string literals. You would need `{'T','e','s','t','\0'}` to be equivalent to `"Test"`.

Comment: ````char * str = "Test"; ```` seems to be acceptable everywhere, also here https://ideone.com/l/cpp,  no error or warning, my g++  and gcc are 9.3.0. Is this outdated?

Comment: @AlbertGLieu It hasn't been allowed since C++11. See [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes) : "String literals are not convertible or assignable to non-const CharT*. An explicit cast (e.g. const_cast) must be used if such conversion is wanted. (since C++11)" This is not my opinion, it is factually not allowed by the language. By default even gcc 9.3.0 produces a warning, so your configuration must be silencing it : https://godbolt.org/z/aG54csajr

Comment: @ François Andrieux thank you so much for sharing you knowledge and your precious time.

Comment: @AlbertGLieu GCC provides a lot of non-standard extensions that are enabled by default. It will allow all sorts of code that is not normally allowed in C++ to compile and run, but it leaves the code non-portable (you have GCC C++ code, not C++ code). The most notorious is probably variable length arrays. I recommend disabling these extension by using the compilation flags `-pedantic` and `-Werror`.